# How SAML 2.0 Authentication Contexts works in following scenario?

Tags: saml-2.0

I would like to build SAML request in such a way that it support both Windows based Authentication and Form Based Authentication.

**Scenario 1**

ADFS Authentication policies are set to Windows based Authentication and Form Based Authentication.
If both authentications are set first priority should be given to Windows based Authentication.

**Scenario 2**

ADFS Authentication policy is set to Form Based Authentication.
In this case Form based authentication should be done.

My Question is how to set RequestedAuthnContext in SAML AuthnRequest so that above scenarios are covered.

**Which Comparison Type should be used (MINIMUM,EXACT,MAXIMUM,BETTER)?**

This is code snippet

```
    RequestedAuthnContext requestedAuthnContext = SAMLUtils.buildSAMLObject(RequestedAuthnContext.class);
    requestedAuthnContext.setComparison(AuthnContextComparisonTypeEnumeration.MINIMUM);

    AuthnContextClassRef windowsAuthnContextClassRef = SAMLUtils.buildSAMLObject(AuthnContextClassRef.class);
    windowsAuthnContextClassRef.setAuthnContextClassRef("urn:federation:authentication:windows");

    AuthnContextClassRef passwordAuthnContextClassRef = SAMLUtils.buildSAMLObject(AuthnContextClassRef.class);
    passwordAuthnContextClassRef.setAuthnContextClassRef(AuthnContext.PPT_AUTHN_CTX);


    requestedAuthnContext.getAuthnContextClassRefs().add(windowsAuthnContextClassRef);
    requestedAuthnContext.getAuthnContextClassRefs().add(passwordAuthnContextClassRef);
```

My Question is how to set RequestedAuthnContext in SAML AuthnRequest so that above scenarios are covered.

I tried all Comparison Types. But Expected scenarios are not working.

Answer (score 2):

The SAML spec ([Core with errata](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/56777/sstc-saml-core-errata-2.0-wd-07-diff.pdf), section 3.3.2.2.1) says this about RequestedAuthnContext element:

> If ordering is relevant to the evaluation of the
>   request, then the set of supplied references MUST be evaluated as an
>   ordered set, where the first element is the most preferred
>   authentication context class or declaration. For example, ordering is
>   significant when using this element in an AuthnRequest message but
>   not in an AuthnQuery message.

The part about evaluation as an ordered set was clarified in the errata revision of the spec

The comparison rules:

> If Comparison is set to "exact" or omitted, then the resulting
>   authentication context in the authentication statement MUST be the
>   exact match of at least one of the authentication contexts specified.
>
> If Comparison is set to "minimum", then the resulting authentication
>   context in the authentication statement MUST be at least as strong (as
>   deemed by the responder) as one of the authentication contexts
>   specified.
>
> If Comparison is set to "better", then the resulting authentication
>   context in the authentication statement MUST be stronger (as deemed by
>   the responder) than any one of the authentication contexts specified.
>
> If Comparison is set to "maximum", then the resulting authentication
>   context in the authentication statement MUST be as strong as possible
>   (as deemed by the responder) without exceeding the strength of at
>   least one of the authentication contexts specified.

Our translation of your scenario:

1. Windows auth should take precedence over form-based auth
2. Form-based auth should be the fallback

The most spec-compliant way of implementing the request is

```
requestedAuthnContext.setComparison(AuthnContextComparisonTypeEnumeration.EXACT);
...
requestedAuthnContext.getAuthnContextClassRefs().add(windowsAuthnContextClassRef);
requestedAuthnContext.getAuthnContextClassRefs().add(passwordAuthnContextClassRef);
```

If your ADFS policy has Windows auth and Form-based auth as selected options, the IdP should select Windows-based auth since it's referenced first in the authentication request. If your ADFS policy contains only Form-based auth, the IdP should go with that since it still exactly matches one of the two auth contexts in your authentication request.

If you did NOT have control over ADFS setup and you could not guarantee the auth options chosen in ADFS policy, then a  *safer* implementation would be to use Minimum as the comparison strength:

```
requestedAuthnContext.setComparison(AuthnContextComparisonTypeEnumeration.MINIMUM);
...
requestedAuthnContext.getAuthnContextClassRefs().add(windowsAuthnContextClassRef);
requestedAuthnContext.getAuthnContextClassRefs().add(passwordAuthnContextClassRef);
```

So far we've talked about the spec perspective but does ADFS respect the spec and implement it correctly? ADFS 2.0 [claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/adfs-2.0/ee895365(v=msdn.10)) to do so with a short list of [supported auth contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/adfs-2.0/hh599318%28v%3Dmsdn.10%29). On ADFS 3.0 there's at least one [report](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/794b27ac-2074-4ac7-b61d-919f56dfddfe/forms-authentication-fba-is-used-instead-of-windows-wia-for-one-relying-party-trust?forum=ADFS) of this feature being broken (allegedly). Verification of this scenario on ADFS 4.0 and 5.0 would be an interesting bullet point, perhaps someone can comment.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the Authentication Context is an abstraction.

Which actual Authentication mechanism is really used by the IdP is totally up to the IdP.

Even if you request 'SPNEGO Kerberos' ("urn:federation:authentication:windows") the IdP may use a totally different mechanism.

Furthermore there is no specification that defines an order upon Authentication Context Class Refs ... again it's up to the IdP implementation to decide which mechanism it considers stronger than another.

From that respect you may use 'MINIMUM' as comparison. 'EXACT' may reduce the probability for successful SSO flow.